# How to use Google Analytics Site Search when the search term is not a query parameter?

Tags: google-analytics

My site search works as follows:

- client types query into form and presses submit
- it GETs the search page /search?q=keyword
- that page redirecs the client to /products/keyword, which shows the search results

How can I use Site Search for Google Analytics with my setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the [recommendation for POST-based search](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1012264)? Basically you have the analytics code on the results page "lie" to GA and send a virtual pageview with your `/search?q=keyword` URL. You're obviously not issuing POST queries, but the underlying problem being addressed isn't really about the request method, just that you have a URL with no query parameter.

Comment: I hadn't read that article. It seems to cover only an old JS, though? Mine begins: `var _gaq = _gaq || [];  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);`

Comment: `_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/url']);` [seems](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview) to be the current way of doing this. I'll try and see if it works.